# Find files matching template and remove

Tags: files, find, filenames

I have a large amount of folders and files. 
I need to parse it and find only those with the extension `xmp` to finally remove them.

How can I achieve this and keep track of the name of the removed files?

To find: I know I can use `find /path -name "*.xmp"`
But how can I run two commands on the output? keep file path and name in `removelist.txt` and remove it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With GNU *find's* **`-fprint`** and **`-delete`** actions:

```
find . -name "*.xmp" -fprint "removelist.txt" -delete
```

- `-fprint file` - print the full file name into file `file`. If `file` does not exist when `find` is run, it is created; if it does exist, it is truncated.
- `-delete` - delete files

Comment: `fprint` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To log the files that were successfully removed, you could do:

```
find . -name '*.xmp' -exec rm -f {} \; -print > removed.txt
```

The `-print` action will only be run if the `-exec` action was successful, that is if `rm` succeeded.

With some `find` implementations, you can replace the `-exec rm -f {} \;` with `-delete` to avoid running one command for each file and avoid some race conditions (initially a FreeBSD extension, but now supported by GNU `find` and a few others).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to execute a compound shell command with `-exec`:

```
find /path -name '*.xmp' -exec sh -c 'echo "$1" >> removelist.txt && rm -f "$1"' sh {} \;
```

Inside a sub-shell both `echo` (appended to `removelist.txt`) and `rm` will be run against each  found file.

Note: The last `sh` is because we are using `-c`. With that flag the first argument that follows is param 0 or `$0` which is supposed to be the name of the shell.

*Gotta admit, @RomanPerekhrest has a nicer answer for this particular case but with the technique here you can do all sorts of things for which there might not be a dedicated `find` flag.* :)

Comment: Efficient answer, thanks. I've accepted the solution from existing flags but this is interesting anyway for other file manipulations.

Comment: @KevinLemaire You accepted the right one. :) But glad you found this one interesting. Cheers.

Comment: Never embed the `{}` in the shell code! What if there's a `$(reboot).xmp` file?

Comment: My approach/tone would have been "Instead of embedding {}, which is dangerous because of ... do this instead ...".. Anyways, with the updated format I'm no longer seeing such process substitution.