# Delete all directory that begin with a particular string

Tags: linux, directory, rm

What command do I have to use to delete all directories that begin with `graphene-80` under the directory `/tmp`?

What can I add to the `rm` command as option?

Comment: Just empty directories, or the contents too?

Answer (score 18):

To delete the directories matching the pattern `graphene-80*` *directly under `/tmp`*, use

```bash
rm -rf /tmp/graphene-80*/
```

Here, the trailing `/` ensures that only directories whose names match the `graphene-80*` pattern are deleted (or symbolic links to directories), and not files etc.

To find the matching directories elsewhere under `/tmp` and delete them wherever they may be, use

```bash
find /tmp -type d -name 'graphene-80*' -prune -exec rm -rf {} +
```

To additionally see the names of the directories as they are deleted, insert `-print` before `-exec`.

The two tests `-type d` and `-name 'graphene-80*'` tests for directories with the names that we're looking for. The `-prune` removes the found directory from the search path (we don't want to look inside these directories as they are being deleted), and the `-exec`, finally, does the actual removal by means of calling `rm`.

---

Addressing question in comments: "How would you delete all files within that directory (not the directory itself)?"

One of the below:

- Recreate the directories after deleting them:

  ```bash
  find /tmp -type d -name 'graphene-80*' -prune \
      -exec rm -rf {} \; -exec mkdir {} +
  ```

  or more efficiently, doing both operations in batches,

  ```bash
  find /tmp -type d -name 'graphene-80*' -prune \
      -exec sh -c 'rm -rf "$@"; mkdir "$@"' sh {} +
  ```

  The benefit of this is the simplicity of the command (compared to the command below).
- Use a small in-line shell script to only delete the names (files and directories) within the found directories:

  ```bash
  find /tmp -type d -name 'graphene-80*' -prune -exec bash -O nullglob -O dotglob -c '
      for dirpath do
          rm -rf "$dirpath"/*
      done' bash {} +
  ```

  This executes a small in-line `bash` script with batches of found directory pathnames. The shell is started with the `nullglob` and `dotglob` shell options set.  The `nullglob` option is used for expanding non-matching shell patterns to *nothing* rather than leaving them unexpanded, and the `dotglob` shell option is used for matching hidden names (`*` does not match hidden names by default).   The script iterates over the given directory paths and empties each directory recursively.

  The benefit of doing it this way is that it adequately deals with found directory paths that happen to be mount points.  The downside is the complexity of the command and the fact that I had to write all this text to describe what it's doing (which means it will potentially be difficult for the next person to take over maintenance of the script).

Comment: How would you delete all files within that directory (not the directory itself)? Thanks!

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein See added bit at the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, however, I don't understand unix commands and when you say "Recreate the directories after deleting them" I guess you are deleting the directories themselves? I only want to find /path/to/dir/FOO1234 and delete its contents for all FOO* directories.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Deleting the directory (and all contents) and then creating the directory again will leave you with a newly created, empty, directory. In effect, the directory at that path has been emptied, which is what you wanted, right?

Comment: Yes, I will try then. I thought there was no need to delete directory, but if that is the way to go, then so be it.

Comment: It works! Is the "\" necessary or is it to indicate new line? I want to use it as a cron command, can I just write ´´´find "/Users/user/Library/Group Containers" -type d -name 'account-*' -prune -exec rm -rf {} \; -exec mkdir {} +´´´ ?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein The backslash at the end of the line is only used for line-continuation.  If you write everything on a single line, then delete it.

Comment: Thanks, and lastly, if I want to target a specific folder within "account*", I have tried doing this but it won't work: ```'account-*/postbox/media'``` Because that is the only subfolder I want to target within ```account-*```.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Instead of a `-name` test, use a `-path` test: `-path '*/account-*/postbox/media' -type d` (etc.)

Comment: You are the boss! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Using [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command:

```
find /tmp -type d -name 'graphene-80*' -delete
```

---

Arguments used:

- `-type` to filter directory only and avoid finding files
- `-name` to find file that match the pattern define between quotes
- `-delete` to delete the result of the find command

---

EDIT:
cleaner with `-delete` like shown in this post:
[Find files matching template and remove](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419798/find-files-matching-template-and-remove)

Comment: cannot delete. directory not empty

Answer (score 0):

To remove just empty directories with names matching `graphene-80*`, either

```
find /tmp -type d -name "graphene-80*" -exec rmdir {} +
```

or

```
find /tmp -type d -name "graphene-80*" -delete
```

(`rmdir` and GNU find should give you errors for the nonempty ones.)

To remove the directories with their contents:

```
find /tmp -type d -name "graphene-80*" -exec rm -r {} \; -prune
```

(With `-exec rm +` you may get errors from `rm` if there are nested matching directories; and without `-prune`, from `find` since it tries to descend to the just-removed directories.)

Comment: Why not just `find /tmp -name 'graphene-80*' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf {} +`?

Answer (score -4):

You can use the following command: **UPDATED**

```
find /tmp -type d -name 'graphene-80*' -prune -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Comment: (1) [Please don’t use the output of `find` as the input, or arguments, to another command.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/80216 "Why is looping over find’s output bad practice?") (2) The question says “all directories *that **begin with*** a particular string”.  Your answer finds only directories whose name ***is*** a particular string.

Comment: Well, if you'd put an * after the desired string fo the directories, then that'd do it. Thanks for sharing the link though.

Comment: This command is dangerous

Comment: If the found name is found in a directory path where one of the directories contain spaces in its name, or where some directory name is a globbing pattern, or combination of these, then this may delete files that you don't want to delete.

Comment: Your updated answer is _good_ (apart from lacking explanation), but it's also _identical_ to already posted answers.